# SQL Server Update with Sub Query Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does this query using a temporary table for a list of ids and then subsequent updates run quicker

```
        DECLARE @temp TABLE
        (
           id int
        );
        INSERT INTO 
            @temp 
        select a.Id from aa a
        inner join bb b on b.id = a.source_id
        inner join cc c on c.document_id = a.id

        update aa set updated_at = GETDATE()
        where id in (select * from @temp)
```

Compared to this  `UPDATE` query which uses a subquery to select a list of ids which takes much longer.

```
        update aa set updated_at = GETDATE()
        where id in (select a.Id from aa a
        inner join bb b on b.id = a.source_id
        inner join cc c on c.document_id = a.id)
```

Comment: Check the execution plans

Comment: please post both execution plans

Answer (score 1):

Why are you repeating the `aa` table in the subquery?  Does this do the same thing?

```
update aa
    set updated_at = GETDATE()
    where a.source_id in (select b.Id
                          from b.id join
                               cc c
                               on c.document_id = a.id
                         );
```

There may be circumstances where they are not the same, but I am guessing this is the logic.

Also, you can write this without a subquery at all:

```
update a
    set updated_at = GETDATE()
    from aa a inner join
         bb b
         on b.id = a.source_id inner join
         cc c 
         on c.document_id = a.id;
```

I would expect this to have good performance -- unless the joins result in many repeated records for a given row in `aa`.